# How to get particular data from column of table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i have this type of table. which is in the below image.

```
Age    Height    Weight    Smoker    SelfAssessedHealthStatus
                ___    ______    ______    ______    ________________________

    Smith       38       71       176      true             Excellent        
    Johnson     43       69       163      false            Fair             
    Williams    38       64       131      false            Good             
    Jones       40       67       133      false            Fair             
    Brown       49       64       119      false            Good             
    Davis       46       68       142      false            Good             
    Miller      33       64       142      true             Good             
    Wilson      40       68       180      false            Good             
    Moore       28       68       183      false            Excellent
```

now I need only the row where "Good". this type of data is available in last column.
please help. I am new to MATLAB.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], we cannot tell you how to interact with an _image_ of your data, it could be lots of different data types which require different methods of interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a similar xlsx-file and next read it with **readtable** function

```
T = readtable('test.xlsx','ReadVariableNames',false)
```

[image: You can see the example]

Then you can make logical array with detecting rows you need:

```
idx = ismember(T.Var5,'LBNP:30')
```

And next just select these rows:

```
T(idx,:)
```

[image: The result]